# Symfony2 - inject static class into service (ImageWorkshop)

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I'm creating a service that uses ImageWorkshop.  In order to init a new image, I need to call:

```
$layer = ImageWorkshop::initFromPath(__DIR__.'/../path/to/myimage.jpg');
```

I'd like to inject ImageWorkshop as a dependency, but I can't figure out how to do this since it uses static methods.  I know I could just call ImageWorkshop statically from my service, but I'm trying to declare my dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the perfect use case for service factories.

You declare your `$layer` as a service and create it with the static factory method in the service container.

```
services:
    myimage_layer:
        class:   PHPImageWorkshop\Core\ImageWorkshopLayer
        factory_class: PHPImageWorkshop\ImageWorkshop
        factory_method: initFromPath
        arguments:
            - "%kernel.root_dir%/../path/to/myimage.jpg"
```

Now you can inject the `myimage_layer` service into your service as a service argument.

**EDIT:** If you need the `ImageWorkshop` directly to call them, but don't want to write `ImageWorkshop::initFromPath('...')` directly in your code, you can decouple it with the class name. It's not really useful, because `ImageWorkshop` is not directly replaceable, but it helps for mocking in tests.

```
services:
    myimage_whatever:
        class:   Acme\Bundle\AcmeBundle\Image\Whatever
        arguments:
            - "PHPImageWorkshop\\ImageWorkshop"
```

Your service:

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\AcmeBundle\Image;

class Whatever
{
    private $imageWorkshop;

    public function __construct($imageWorkshop)
    {
        $this->imageWorkshop = $imageWorkshop;
    }

    public function doWhatever($path)
    {
        $layer = $this->imageWorkshop::initFromPath($path);
        // ...
    }
 }
```

Beware yourself, `$imageWorkshop` is no instance. Instead it's a string containing the fully qualified class name of `ImageWorkshop` to call the static method on it. I hope this should work.

Reference for calling a static method on a string variable containing the class name: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#example-214

Comment: My only problem with this is that I won't know the path of the image passed to initFromPath at the time of injection.  This needs to be set in a call to the service, for example $myImageWorkshopService->init($myfile)

Comment: In that case, use @wonde 's solution.  But I don't think there is really much point in adding another layer of complexity.  Trying to swap a different image processor in will be problematical at best.

Comment: You are right, might as well just use it statically within my service.

Comment: @StevenMusumeche please see my edit, I hope this may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a wrapper class and implement the static class methods in it

e.g

```
Class ImageWorkshopWrapper
{
  public function initFromPath($path)
  {
    ImageWorkshop::initFromPath($path);
  }

}
```

and inject ImageWorkshopWrapper class